# Java Reading Text File Currently Open For Writing

Tags: java, file, io

I am wondering what the best way to read from a file that is currently open for writing.

The program handles read / write requests.

In the program, a PrintWriter is used to write to the file.

```
PrintWriter serverLog = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("server"+processID+".log"));
serverLog.println("arbitrary text");
```

I have a function that is accessed that needs to read from the file. No writes will be performed when I need to access the file for reading.

Using the Scanner or BufferedReader methods for reading don't appear to work. 
The only option I can think of is to close the PrintWriter, read the file, and then re-open the PrintWriter with 'append' mode, but that seems like a very poor option.

Comment: 'That seems like a very poor option'. It's a very poor design altogether. This is a job for a database.

Answer (score 1):

Consider java.io.RandomAccessFile. This class can both read and write from an open file. Not very convenient to read / write text though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't perform two modes(read and write) at the same time.